# Telegram Automation

Tags: telegram

I'm working on a program, it's mission is that we define some number for it (some of our mobile numbers) and it should register them in Telegram, and then gets all messages that send to that number. As you may know, the registration in Telegram needs providing a phone number and after that a validate the number by a code that is sent from Telegram.

I read Telegram API, but it was complex and with no certain example and explanation.
I need your help.

Answer (score 6):

To implement Telegram chat,

1. First of all, you should obtain your own api_id and api_hash as described [here](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).
2. Read [the document](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description) and get ideas about the terms used in the Protocol which will be useful to go further.
3. Create a TCP connection with Telegram Server via port 443.
4. Telegram uses a key called 'Authorization Key' (ie Auth key) for Encryption/Decryption and it will be derived in both Server and Client using Diffie-Hellman Algorithm by various steps. You can create this Auth key by following the steps explained [here](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key) and you can also see a sample for this process [here](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key).
5. When you are successful at all the above steps, you will finally be able to receive 'dh_gen_ok' response from Telegram server.
6. Now you can send RPC queries (Telegram APIs). The list of APIs is given in this link https://core.telegram.org/methods

These are just the brief points which will help you to get an idea about this. To implement the whole process, you need to read the documents and get to know the flow and all its limitations. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, is there any available sample source for this ?

Comment: @alone You can check out Java sample telegram-api project `http://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this

BUT

first of all, you should write a program (class) for one number

and after that
create another instances of that class for another numbers

if you write main class (work by One phoneNumber)

it's very simple to extend you program to work by many numbers


Good Luck !!!

Comment: Thank you Bahram for your answer, can you give more information please ? Is there any available code ? can i do it with Telegram API?

Comment: you can check this link 
https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop
This is good example